# 3 tier architecture, could not find file

Tags: vb.net, 3-tier

Hi i'm developing windows desktop app using 3 tier architecture with VB, when i run the application i get `"Could not find file 'C:\Users\PHU-T\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Visual_Basic_2013_SBS\Chapter 09\Orange Student\bin\Debug\Students.accdb"` error. The `Student.accdb` file is the `Data Access Layer project`, the file is copied to `bin\Debug` folders of the `Data Access Layer` and `Business Logic Layer projects` but not in the `Presentation Layer`. I don't want to create fixed data source like `'C:\Users\PHU-T\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Students.accdb'` as the project will be submitted for marking. How can i solve this? i'm using the data source below.

`Data Source=|DataDirectory|\Students.accdb`

[image]

Comment: Does Orange_Student_PL have a reference to the DAL project?

Comment: Why would the presentation layer have a reference to the DAL project?  That would (to me at least) break the concept behind n-tier...

Comment: @MikeC i have added reference to DAL project and it's working now, thanks.

Comment: @Phuti, let me post that as an answer for you to accept then.

Comment: @Tim that's why i didn't add reference to it at the first place.

Comment: @Phuti If adding the project as a reference makes it work, I'd take a second look at how the layers are designed, because the presentation layer shouldn't need any knowledge of the DAL to work.

Comment: It's more about how Visual Studio outputs the files.  It's not really that the code in the presentation layer needs to reference anything in the DAL layer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a reference to the DAL project from your PL project in order for the .accdb file to end up in the output directory of your main application.

**Update**

I could not reproduce this myself in Visual Studio 2013 with a similar project setup.  Referencing the BLL project from the main app was all I needed to copy the DB.  You might want to check the properties of the .accdb file in your project and make sure it's set to "Copy Always".